# NumericUpDown / ReadOnly, but contextmenu?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a NumericUpdown - which for certain Users is readonly.

This also disables the contextmenu of the control (right click) - which is not intendet in this case, cause it serves some functions like copy value etc.

Is there a way to render the control readonly, but keep the contextmenu enabled?

Something like overriding `OnContextMenuShown()` to remove the readonly constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Problem is, that - when the control is `readonly` - clicks are send to the parent container, rather than to the control itself. So, not even possible to override the controls own Mouse-Events to handle this.

Therefore, I've now added a logic to hook into the parents `OnClick`-Event, whenever a `NumericUpDown` is set to readonly.

Ofc. if it is set back to `Enabled`, the handler needs to be removed again.

```
private MouseEventHandler RightClickParentHandler;

...

//hook into the parent containers MouseClick-Listener to detect rightclicks that should appear
//on this (readonly) control. Remove Listener, if control becomes enabled again.
if (this.ReadOnly)
{
    if (this.RightClickParentHandler == null)
    {
        this.RightClickParentHandler = new MouseEventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
            NumericUpDown ctl = this.Parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location) as NumericUpDown;

            if (ctl == this)
            {
                if (this.ContextMenuStrip != null)
                {
                    this.ContextMenuStrip.Show(this.Parent, e.Location);
                }
            }
        });

        this.Parent.MouseClick += this.RightClickParentHandler;
    }
}
else
{
    if (this.RightClickParentHandler != null)
    {
        this.Parent.MouseClick -= this.RightClickParentHandler;
        this.RightClickParentHandler = null;
    }
}
```